# sap.m.Input change event is triggered when clicking on CheckBox

Tags: javascript, html, sapui5

I have two controls in my page i.e. **sap.m.Input** and **sap.m.CheckBox**. There is a **change event** attached to input field which *gives an error bar if input text is not matched with the regex*. This change event is triggered on clicking out of focus of the input field. **Clicking on checkbox will hide this input and show a third control**. Now if i enter something in input field which will not match regex and click on checkbox, It is triggering changeEvent of Input and not even selecting the checkbox. I tried many things like checking in change event whether checkbox is ticked or not, attached a click event on checkbox but no solution. 
Please help me so that i will be able to **determine the click on checkbox if the current focus is on input field**

Here is an example at [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/susozar/1/edit?html,output). Here error will be thrown if input text contains @ and change event is triggered.

```
var textInput = new sap.m.Text({text:"Area:"})
var inputField =new sap.m.Input("inptId",{
  change:function(oEvent){

    sap.ui.getCore().byId("barId").setVisible(oEvent.getParameters().value.includes("@"));

  }
});

var select  = new sap.m.Select("select",
                               {visible:false,
                                items:[new sap.ui.core.Item({text:"India"}),
                                      new sap.ui.core.Item({text:"US"}),
                                       new sap.ui.core.Item({text:"UK"})
                                      ]
                               })
var hBox = new sap.m.HBox({items:[textInput,inputField,select]})

  var bar = new sap.m.Bar("barId",{
    visible:false,
    contentMiddle:new sap.m.Text({text:"Error"})
  });

  var chkBox = new sap.m.CheckBox("chkBxId",{
  text:"Select from dropdown",
  select:function(oEvent){        
    var selected = oEvent.getParameters().selected;
    sap.ui.getCore().byId("inptId").setVisible(!selected);
     sap.ui.getCore().byId("select").setVisible(selected);
    sap.ui.getCore().byId("barId").setVisible(false);
  }
});
var vBox = new sap.m.VBox({
  items:[bar,hBox,chkBox]
});
```

In this example it is happening sometimes not always but in my project its happening always as there are lot of validations are happening in change event.

Comment: have you tried using livechange event of input

Comment: @suryabhanmourya yes i have tried it but the requirement is to validate text when enter is pressed or focus is moved out not on live change

Answer (score 1):

@Ashish for `focus` out try following code.

```
this.getView().byId("input").addEventDelegate({
  onfocusout: function() {
    console.log("focus lost !!");
  }
}
```

and for `enter key` press use following code

```
.addEventDelegate({
  onkeypress: function(e) {
    if (e.which === 13) {
      do your stuff;
    }
  }
})
```

once focus is out it will trigger function provide in `onfocusout` and while on focus if enter key is pressed it will trigger function provide in `onkeypress` event.
Also you can merge this in one.

```
addEventDelegate({
  onkeypress: function(e) {
    console.log("Enter pressed fouse out", e.which);
  },
  onfocusout: function() {
    do your stuff!
  }
})
```